# Multithreaded code not taking else branch

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, pthreads

I'm currently writing a primitive client-server program in C for Linux. The server is multithreaded. I've written the following code for the client and server, respectively:

**Server** (compiled using `gcc -o -lpthreads server server.c`):

```
#include <stdio.h>                      
#include <string.h>                     
#include <arpa/inet.h>                  
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dirent.h>


void lsfunc(char *path, char *buffer) {
    int pointer = sprintf(buffer, "User ID\tGroup ID\tFilename\n");
    int cx = 0; 
    DIR *mydir;
    struct dirent *myfile;
    struct stat mystat;
    mydir = opendir(path);
    myfile = readdir(mydir);
    while ((myfile = readdir(mydir)) != NULL) {    
        stat(myfile->d_name, &mystat);    
        cx = sprintf(buffer+pointer, "%lu\t%lu\t%s\n", (unsigned long int) mystat.st_uid, (unsigned long int) mystat.st_gid, myfile->d_name);
        pointer += cx;
    }
    closedir(mydir);
}

void makedir(char *path, char *prompt) {
    struct stat st = {0};
    if (stat(path, &st) == -1) {
        mkdir(path, 0700);
        sprintf(prompt, "Directory successfully created");
    }
    else {
        sprintf(prompt, "A folder with the same name already exists");
    }
}

void fgetsfunc(char *path, char *buffer) {
    FILE *fp = fopen(path, "r");
    char ch;
    int pointer = 0;
    while ((ch = getc(fp)) != EOF) {
        sprintf(buffer+pointer, "%c", ch);
        pointer += 1;
    }
    fclose(fp);
}   

void fputsfunc(char *path, char *buffer) {
    int resultCode = 0;
    FILE *fp = fopen(path, "w");
    resultCode = fputs(buffer, fp);
    if (resultCode == EOF) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to write.\n");
    }
    fclose(fp);
}

int authenticate(char *username) {
    int error = 0;
    if (*username != 'u') {
        error = -1;
    }
    *username++;
    while (*username != '\0') {
        if (!isdigit(*username)) {
            error = -1;
        }
        *username++;
    }
    return error;
}


void *connectionHandler(void *socket_descriptor) {
    int rcv_retcode, wrt_retcode, error_code;
    int sock = *(int*)socket_descriptor;
    char message_received[100], message_sent[10000];
    char user[5];
    char *greetings;
    char *FAIL = "FAIL";

    greetings = "Welcome user. Enter your username: ";
    write(sock, greetings, strlen(greetings));

    if((rcv_retcode = recv(sock, user, 5, 0)) == -1) {
        perror("Receive failed");
    }

    error_code = authenticate(user);

    if (error_code < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to authenticate user.\n");
        write(sock, FAIL, 5);
    }

    while(1) {
        if((rcv_retcode = recv(sock, message_received, 100, 0)) == -1) {
            perror("Receive failed");
        }

        fprintf(stdout, "Client says: %s\n",message_received);
        const char s[2] = " ";
        const char n[2] = "\n";
        char *token, *command, *path, *input;
        //char writeBuff[1000];
        token = strtok(message_received, s);
        command = token;

        if (strcmp(command, "exit") == 0) {
            close(sock);
            strncpy(message_sent, "Client logged out.", 10000);
        }

        else if (strcmp(command,"ls") == 0) {
            token = strtok(NULL, s);
            path = token;
            lsfunc(path, message_sent);
        }

        else if(strcmp(command,"mkdir") == 0) {
            token = strtok(NULL, s);
            path = token;
            makedir(path, message_sent);
        }

        else if(strcmp(command,"fgets") == 0) {
            token = strtok(NULL, s);
            path = token;
            fgetsfunc(path, message_sent);
        }

        else if(strcmp(command, "fputs") == 0) {
            token = strtok(NULL, s);
            path = token;
            token = strtok(NULL, n);
            input = token;
            printf("%s\n", input);
            fputsfunc(path, input);
            strncpy(message_sent, "Written to file", 10000);
        }
        if ((wrt_retcode = write(sock, message_sent, 10000)) == -1) {
            perror("Write failed");
        }
        message_received[0] = '\0';
        message_sent[0] = '\0';
        //sleep(1);
    }
    close(sock);
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    int socket_retcode, bind_retcode, listen_retcode, acc_retcode, rcv_retcode, wrt_retcode;
    char message_received[100], message_sent[10000];
    struct sockaddr_in server, client;

    if ((socket_retcode = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1) {
        perror("Failed to create socket");
        return -1;
    }

    fprintf(stdout, "Socket created successfully\n");

    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    server.sin_port = htons(4000);
    char *server_add = inet_ntoa(server.sin_addr);
    uint16_t port_num = ntohs(server.sin_port);
    printf("The address of the server is: %s\nThe port number is: %d\n", server_add,port_num);

    if ((bind_retcode = bind(socket_retcode, (struct sockaddr*)&server, sizeof(server))) == -1) {
        perror("Bind failed");
        return -1;
    }

    if((listen_retcode = listen(socket_retcode, 20)) == -1) {
        perror("Listen failed");
        return -1;
    }
    int c = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    pthread_t thread_id;

    while ((acc_retcode = accept(socket_retcode, (struct sockaddr*)&client, (socklen_t*)&c))) {
        printf("Connection accepted\n");

        if (pthread_create (&thread_id, NULL, connectionHandler, (void*)&acc_retcode) < 0) {
            perror("Thread creation failed");
        }

        printf("Handler assigned\n");
    }
    if (acc_retcode < 0) {
        perror("Accept failed");
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Client**:

```
#include <stdio.h>              
#include <string.h>             
#include <arpa/inet.h>           

#define OK       0
#define NO_INPUT 1
#define TOO_LONG 2 

static int getLine(char *prompt, char *buff, size_t sz) {
    int ch, extra;

    if (prompt != NULL) {
        printf ("%s", prompt);
        fflush (stdout);
    }
    if (fgets (buff, sz, stdin) == NULL) {
        return NO_INPUT;
    }

    if (buff[strlen(buff)-1] != '\n') {
        extra = 0;
        while (((ch = getchar()) != '\n') && (ch != EOF))
            extra = 1;
        return (extra == 1) ? TOO_LONG : OK;
    }

    buff[strlen(buff)-1] = '\0';
    return OK;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char IP[20], message[100], rcv_message[10000], filewriter_buffer[10000], check;
    char greeting[100], username[5], user_auth[5];

    int port_num, flag = 1;
    int client_retcode, IP_retcode, message_retcode, cnct_retcode, send_retcode, rcv_retcode;
    int logon_rcv, send_usr, user_rcv;

    struct sockaddr_in r_server;
    client_retcode = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);

    if (client_retcode == -1) {
        perror("Failed to create socket.");
        return -1;
    }

    if (getLine("Enter IP: ", IP, sizeof(IP)) != OK) {
        fprintf(stderr, "No/Invalid IP provided.\n");
        return -1;
    }

    fprintf(stdout, "Enter Port Number: ");

    if (scanf("%d%c", &port_num, &check) != 2 || check != '\n') {
        printf("Non-integer port provided.\n");
        return -1;
    }

    r_server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    r_server.sin_port = htons(port_num);
    r_server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(IP);
    cnct_retcode = connect(client_retcode, (struct sockaddr *)&r_server, sizeof(r_server));

    if (cnct_retcode == -1) {
        perror("Connect failed");
        return -1;
    }

    fprintf(stdout, "Connection to server on %s:%d successful\n", IP, port_num);

    while(1) {
        logon_rcv = recv(client_retcode, greeting, 100, 0); 
        if (logon_rcv == -1) {
            perror("Receive failed");
        }
        if (getLine(greeting, username, sizeof(username)) != OK) {
            printf("No/Invalid input\n");
            return -1;
        }

        send_usr = send(client_retcode, username, 5, 0);
        if (send_usr == -1) {
            perror("Send failed");
            return -1;
        }

        user_rcv = recv(client_retcode, user_auth, 5, 0);

        if (user_rcv == -1) {
            perror("Receive failed");
            return -1;
        }


        if (strcmp(user_auth, "FAIL") == 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Wrong username. Exiting...\n");
            break;
        }

        else {

            if (getLine("Enter command: ", message, sizeof(message)) != OK) {
                printf("No/Invalid command provided\n");
                return -1;
            }

            if(strcmp(message, "exit") == 0) {
                send_retcode = send(client_retcode, message, 100, 0);                           
                if(send_retcode == -1) {
                    perror("Send failed");
                    return -1;
                }
                break;
            } 

            send_retcode = send(client_retcode, message, 100, 0);                           
            if(send_retcode == -1) {
                perror("Send failed");
                return -1;
            }

            rcv_retcode = recv(client_retcode, rcv_message, 10000, 0);                      

            if (rcv_retcode == -1) {
                perror("Receive failed");
                return -1;
            }
            printf("Server says: %s\n", rcv_message);
            message[0] = '\0';
            rcv_message[0] = '\0';                                      
        }
        close(client_retcode);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

As might be clear from the code, I'm not a very good C programmer. When executing the program, I get to the point where the client provides the username and the server checks for its validity. Problem is: it stops after that. If the username is valid, the `else` branch on the client side is never taken, and nothing happens on the respective shells afterwards. It works pretty well if I take out the entire `if-else` and don't check for valid usernames, but that's an important part of my implementation and I can't make do without that. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @JS1 Fixed that, but still doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: _"If the username is valid, the `else` branch on the client side is never taken"_ If the `if` was reached, and the username was valid, the `else` branch would be taken. So either your compiler can't get a simple if-else right, or the `if` is never reached. I'll leave you to work out which of those possibilities is more likely. Hint: lots of very good C programmers use your compiler too and would have noticed if it didn't support if-else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a number of critical bugs, but I think the reason why you are seeing the described behavior is:

In `server.c`:

```c
if((rcv_retcode = recv(sock, user, 5, 0)) == -1) {
    perror("Receive failed");
}

error_code = authenticate(user);

if (error_code < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to authenticate user.\n");
    write(sock, FAIL, 5);
}

while(1) {
    if((rcv_retcode = recv(sock, message_received, 100, 0)) == -1) {
        perror("Receive failed");
    }
    ...
}
```

If the username is valid, your server doesn't return any response and just waits. Your server needs to respond if the username is valid, or else your client sits here waiting forever in `client.c`:

```c
    /* Ends up waiting here forever */
    user_rcv = recv(client_retcode, user_auth, 5, 0);

    if (user_rcv == -1) {
        perror("Receive failed");
        return -1;
    }


    if (strcmp(user_auth, "FAIL") == 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Wrong username. Exiting...\n");
        break;
    }
```

To fix this, make a change to `server.c` (indicated by a comment):

```c
if((rcv_retcode = recv(sock, user, 5, 0)) == -1) {
    perror("Receive failed");
}

error_code = authenticate(user);

if (error_code < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to authenticate user.\n");
    write(sock, FAIL, 5);
}

write(sock, "butt", 5); /* Send something that isn't FAIL */

while(1) {
    if((rcv_retcode = recv(sock, message_received, 100, 0)) == -1) {
        perror("Receive failed");
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that fixes the problem. However, I cannot handle multiple connections now. If any client issues the `exit` command, the code on server side automatically dies and gives `Segmentation fault`. I know I'm being a bother, but I'm relatively new to programming. I'd be grateful if you could point me in the right direction as to how I should handle multiple connections.

Comment: It is good that you are willing to learn. I would recommend you create new questions to get the quickest answers for designing your multithreaded server. If you do, I will make sure to look at it later, too.

Comment: As for the SegFault on `exit`, it's because you don't kill the `connectionHandler` thread after calling `close(sock)` in the `exit` handling block. It just continues, and invokes `write()` on a closed socket, then loops and invokes `recv` again even though the socket is closed. And then you try to call `strtok` on `message_received[0] = '\0';`, so it seg faults.